# cant set overwrites when creating category

Tags: discord.py

I've watched a youtube tutorial about creating channels with overwrites but I still don't get why this code doesn't work

```
varCategory = await message.guild.create_category(name=args[1], overwrites={overwrite(message.guild.default_role,view_channel=False,send_messages=False)}, reason=None, position=0)
```

I get the error init() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`view_channel` is from the old `async` version. Now you can just set it with `read_messages` or `send_messages`, which would both prevent a user from messaging in a channel.

Here I have corrected your code and tested it, you can also choose if the author of the command should have access to the channel.

```py
guild = ctx.guild
member = ctx.author
overwrites = {
    guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False),
    member: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
    }
channel = await guild.create_text_channel(args=[1], overwrites=overwrites)
```